# 4 walls of domino tower

Tags: dominoes

How can I rearrange the domino tiles below so that all vertical columns has 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. 
While all the horizontal rows has 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 + duplicate ?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, what do you mean with "+duplicate"? Could you clarify the question?

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know how

Comment: @TSLF if this isn't your puzzle you need to credit the source otherwise it is plagiarism

Comment: I managed to do all vertical but I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: By duplicate do you mean you can have one duplicate value.  For example row 1 will contain (0,1), (2,3), (4,5),(6,4) where 4 is a duplicate or (0,1), (2,3), (4,5),(6,6) where 6 is a tile with the same value on both sides.  And are you supposed to have 2 (5,6) tiles or should the last one be (6,6)

Comment: @Alenanno-there are 8 monominoes  on the rows so there will be a duplicate,@ gtwebb-yes

Comment: The tiles form a standard set except for an extra 5/6 and a missing 6/6. Is this what you intended?

Comment: @Penguino-corrected that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the comments to the question, the tiles in the picture form a standard set except for an extra 5/6 and a missing 6/6. If we assume the picture to be correct,

> It's impossible, as there aren't enough sixes to cover all 8 columns.

Otherwise, making the assumption that we are supposed to arrange a standard set:

> Any double already creates a duplicate, so we have to have one double in each row. Therefore, I started by placing all doubles in the first column. To keep the pattern going, I arranged all tiles with a difference of 1 or 6 in the second column, differences of 2 or 5 went in the third column, and finally 3 or 4 in the fourth column:
>
> ```
>  00  23  46  51
>  11  34  50  62
>  22  45  61  03
>  33  56  02  14
>  44  60  13  25
>  55  01  24  36
>  66  12  35  40
> ```

Comment: Its corrected , (5,6)  now (6,6)